# Is it possible to reuse the Toolbar Overflow menu elsewhere?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to be able to add an additional 'toolbar' to the bottom of the screen to show commands that are only possible in certain situations (e.g. the operations on the elements the user has selected in a displayed list). Is is possible to create a second toolbar (or maybe just create another Overflow menu that I could place where I'd like)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toolbar is a special case designed for its specific location. However adding commands to the bottom of the page is pretty trivial. You can do something such as this:

```
Form myForm = new Form("My Form", new BorderLayout());
Container formContent = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
myForm.add(CENTER, formContent);

// add what you want to formContent, you can also make it scrollable on the Y axis etc.

Container commands = GridLayout.encloseIn(3, new Button(commandA), new Button(commandB), new Button(commandC));
myForm.add(SOUTH, commands);
```

Comment: Thanks, I already expected to do something like that, but there will be more commands than what will fit in nicely. So I’ll need some kind of overflow menu to show the less used commands and I was hoping I could reuse something already existing in CN1

Comment: We used to have something like that but it predated the toolbar. I wouldn't recommend using the "overflow" menu. It's pretty trivial to do anyway. Just do something like: `Button overflow = new Button("...");` Then in the action listener just show a dialog using `showPopup()` on the overflow. That's technically what we do to implement the overflow.

Comment: I've just started experimenting with this, but I cannot find a way of deactivating the tinting of the background Form when showing the dialog with showPopupDialog(). Toolbar uses Form.setTintColor() combined with Form.tint=false but Form.tint is protected so not accessible. Is there another way of preventing the tinting?

Comment: Where does `Toolbar` invoke `setTintColor`? If you invoke it with 0 it should disable the tinting. No need to access the field.

Comment: When I try this code it doesn't work (form is tinted dark): Form hi = new Form("Welcome");
Dialog menuDialog = new Dialog("");
Button menuCmd = new Button("A button");
menuDialog.add(menuCmd);
Button showMenu = new Button();
showMenu.setCommand(Command.createMaterial("Menu", FontImage.MATERIAL_MORE_VERT, (e) -> {
    menuDialog.getComponentForm().setTintColor(0);
    menuDialog.showPopupDialog(showMenu);
}));
hi.add(showMenu);
hi.show();

Comment: ` menuDialog.getComponentForm().setTintColor(0); ` is incorrect. Use `hi.setTintColor(0);`. Dialog is a form and you're setting the tint color on the dialog instead of its parent form.

Comment: Should have known that, thanks!