# Form shown via a Command in a Dialog doesn't show correctly

Tags: codenameone

I've made my own popup/overflow menu (as discussed here: [Is it possible to reuse the Toolbar Overflow menu elsewhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66427359/is-it-possible-to-reuse-the-toolbar-overflow-menu-elsewhere/66432254?noredirect=1#comment123765822_66432254)).

The code worked OK, but then I added a menu command that displays another Form. When that command is clicked, the other Form just flashes by and is immediately replaced by the first form.

The code below shows this. Click "show my menu" and then click "PopupCmd" in the menu. I want the Form2 to remain visible (to allow the user to do other things and then return back to Form1), but it just flashes and Form1 is immediately shown again.

I guess I'm missing something obvious, but I've spend a lot of time debugging and testing various options without finding any solution, so I'm hoping someone can spot the issue.

```
Form form1 = new Form("Form1", BoxLayout.y());
form1.setName("FORM1"); //for debugging
Dialog myMenu = new Dialog("test menu dialog", BoxLayout.y());
myMenu.setName("POPUPMENU"); //for debugging
myMenu.setAutoDispose(true); 
myMenu.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true); 

myMenu.add(new Button(Command.createMaterial("PopupCmd", FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS, (ev) -> {
    Form form2 = new Form("FORM2");
    form2.setName("FORM2"); //for debugging
    form2.show();
})));

Button showMenu = new Button("show my menu");
showMenu.addActionListener((e) -> {

    myMenu.showPopupDialog(showMenu); //get user-selected cmd
});
form1.add(showMenu);
form1.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `Dialog` is disposed it goes back to its parent `Form`. So what happened here is that the `Command` showed the new `Form` then its dispose call went back to the previous `Form`.

You have the following options:

```
myMenu.setAutoDispose(false);
```

That would disable the automatic disposing and solve that.

A possible better approach would be to let the `Dialog` dispose and then show the next `Form`. This can be accomplished simply by moving the code to the next EDT cycle:

```
myMenu.add(new Button(Command.createMaterial("PopupCmd", FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS, 
(ev) -> callSerially(() -> {
    Form form2 = new Form("FORM2");
    form2.setName("FORM2"); //for debugging
    form2.show();
}))));
```

Notice the extra wrapping of `callSerially`, it assumes a static import of `CN.*` otherwise you can write it as `CN.callSerially`.

Comment: Thanks! Disabling audoDispose is not an option since the menu should disappear if the user clicks outside or re-clicks the showmen cmd icon (like the Overflow menu does). I'll try the second option. However, it is not very easy to figure this out (and I spend at least half a day on it), so maybe something you'll want to improve. I'll submit an RFP :-)

Comment: Confirms the second solution works. Thanks again.

Comment: Making this easier is problematic. There are already several workarounds embedded for that but they never solved all the edge cases. Making all commands us call serially by default is problematic too as it slows down the system and causes other problems. We did this for menus by default but it's impossible to make it generic.